# Plotting patches obtained from surf2patch - Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

After converting a sphere into a patch, I plotted the first vertex of the patch, and realized that the vertex is not on the sphere.

Code

```
[faces, vertices] = surf2patch(sphere(),'triangle');
sphere();
hold on;
plot3(vertices(1,1), vertices(1,2), vertices(1,3),'*r');
```

The resulting figure looks like this

[image]

How can the vertex not be on the surface of the sphere? Am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**

When a function is an argument to another function, *Matlab treats this as a function call with a single return value.*  In the context of our function call above,

`[faces, vertices] = surf2patch(sphere(),'triangle');`

is equivalent to:

```
z = sphere();
[faces, vertices] = surf2patch(z,'triangle');
```

Now recall from the documentation:

`[x, y, z] = sphere()` calculates a set of 3D coordinates, *[x, y, z]*.

`z = sphere()` calculates the same *[x, y, z]* and only returns the *z*.

`sphere()` with (nargout = 0) calculates the same *[x, y, z]*, and plots it. This is the color sphere shown in the diagram above.

Examining the source for *surf2patch.m* shows that when called with a single *z* argument, it assumes values for *x* and *y* automatically. These values are different than the *[x, y, z]* plotted by calling `sphere()` with no arguments.

**Testing**

To see for yourself, trace through the following code with a breakpoint enabled just inside *surf2patch.m*, and examine the input arguments:

```
[x,y,z] = sphere()
[facesA, verticesA] = surf2patch(x,y,z,'triangle')
[facesB, verticesB] = surf2patch(sphere(), 'triangle')
[facesC, verticesC] = surf2patch(z, 'triangle')
```

You see that the output *[facesA, verticesA]* matches the plot from `sphere()`, whereas the second and third call to `surf2patch()` have no input *[x, y]* values, so they get auto-generated to something different than the original *[x,y,z]*.

**Lesson**

If you expect multiple return values, assign them explicitly.